# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

folder structure

```
.
├── myapp
│   ├── api
│   │   └── routes.py
│   ├── app.py
│   |
│   └── site
│       └── routes.py
```

app.py is in myapp folder outside of api folder and site folder

api/routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint
api = Blueprint('api',__name__,url_prefix='api')

@api.route('/userlist/')
def user():
  return { 1: 'user1', 2:'user2'}
```

site/routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

site = Blueprint('site',__name__)

@site.route('/')
def index():
  return 'Welcome to the Home page'
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from .site.routes import site
from .api.routes import api

def create_app():
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.register_blueprint(api)
  app.register_blueprint(site)
  return app
```

i got this error while running flask application using 'flask run' command in terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
  from .site.routes import site
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

i don't understand how to solve this problem.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: share full traceback

Comment: @Олег Гребчук **added**

Comment: @M_x is `app.py` is your execution script or there is another script outside of `myapp` folder which run the project ?

Comment: `app.py` is execution script

Comment: add a `__init__.py` file in `myapp` and inn it write `from . import api, site` and then in `app.py` import items as `from api.routes import api` `from site.route import site`

Comment: @napuzba .. thanks for helping but error just gone by editing `url_prefix='/api'` from `url_prefix='api'` from `myapp/api/routes.py` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a minor change.
old code:

```
api = Blueprint('api',__name__,url_prefix='api')
```

new code:

```
api = Blueprint('api',__name__,url_prefix='/api')
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe Python thinks the dot of your import is a relative import(which it obviously cannot find).

Try to import with the following:  (if app.py is in above your myapp folder)

```
from myapp.site.routes import site
```

Try to import with the following: (if app.py is in your myapp folder)

```
from site.routes import site
```

Comment: got this error while removing **.** `from site.routes import site
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'site.routes'; 'site' is not a package

Comment: your second solution was correct as OP has updated the question statement and `app.py` was in `myapp` folder .

Comment: to be honest, I got a bit confused - I included both statements now, just in case :D

Comment: thanks for helping but error just gone by editing `url_prefix='/api'` from `url_prefix='api'` from `myapp/api/routes.py` file

Answer (score 4):

Please add empty `__init__.py` in each folder:
myapp, api, site

and then try to import
`from myapp.site.routes import site`

Comment: thanks for helping but error just gone by editing `url_prefix='/api'` from `url_prefix='api'` from `myapp/api/routes.py` file